# 2 foreign fields to the same class when using ormlite

Tags: foreign-keys, ormlite

Using ormlite, I have 2 classes: Menu and MenuItem. I want to have 2 foreign fields inside MenuItem that both point to a Menu class. However, this doesn't seem to work. Using only one foreign field for the same class does work. How can I achieve what I want?

```
@DatabaseTable
public class MenuItem {

   /* ... */

   @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "destination_submenu")
    public Menu destinationSubmenu;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "menu")
    public Menu menu;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had used in the Menu class a ForeignCollectionField but because I had 2 foreign keys in MenuItem, it didn't work as expected. The solution was to use foreignColumnName.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Menu {

/* ... */
    @ForeignCollectionField(foreignColumnName = "menu")
    @JsonIgnore
    private ForeignCollection<MenuItem> items;
}
```

Comment: For posterity: foreignColumnName is in the 4.36 release which is currently (March 2012) in SNAPSHOT status.